# How to create a function that print a's and b's but that doesn't print 3 consecutive alphabhet

Tags: python

Pretty much have to print 'a'&'b' of amount of integer from parameter.

```
def function(A,B): 
    pass
```

A or B is integer amount, function(3,5) gonna print 3 a's, and 5 b's like these combinations:

- 'baabbabb'
- 'babababb'
- 'bbabbaab'

but it never print three consecutive alphabet in their combination like this one:

- 'bbaaabbb'

more examples:

```
function(5,3): 'aabbaaba'

function(1,4): 'bbabb'

function(3,3): 'aabbab'
```

Tried using if else and while>=3 but it looks horrendous. Any pointer would be appreciated

```
def solution(A,B):
text = ""
if A > B:
    while (A >= 3 or B >= 3) and A != 0 and B != 0:
        text += 'a' * 1
        A-=1
        text += 'b' * 1
        B-=1
    if text[-1] == 'a':
        text += 'b' * B
        text += 'a' * A
    else:
        text += 'a' * A
        text += 'b' * B
elif A < B:
    while (A >= 3 or B >= 3) and A != 0 and B != 0:
        text += 'b' * 1
        B-=1
        text += 'a' * 1
        A-=1
    if text[-1] == 'a':
        text += 'b' * B
        text += 'a' * A
    else:
        text += 'a' * A
        text += 'b' * B
else:
    while (A >= 3 or B >= 3) and A != 0 and B != 0:
        text+='a' * 1
        A-=1
        text+='b' * 1
        B-=1
    if text[-1] == 'a':
        text += 'b' * B
        text += 'a' * A
    else:
        text += 'a' * A
        text += 'b' * B
return text
pass
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, check [ask] and [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @HenryWoody Edited, what I tried before. It's still failed where the parameter (1,4) which resulting in babbb

Comment: Hello, do you have any constraints about possible combinations? Anyway, you have to take into account the limits, it will no be possible if the difference between A and B is too big

Comment: Does the code you've provided work properly and the issue is just that it "looks horrendous"? Or is there something wrong with the functionality?

Comment: @HenryWoody nope, it doesn't work properly. Like I said it's failed when the parameter (1,4)

Comment: @Christophe the difference A and B shouldn't be more than 3 I think

Comment: It depends... for big figures, the difference can be bigger (ex: aabaabaabaabaab => A=10 & B=5)

Answer (score 1):

I want to show you another way to think about your problem.  What you have there is essentially a binary number, where the digits are 'a' and 'b' instead of 0 and 1.  So, here I run through all of the numbers up to length A+B, then reject any where a run of 3 occur.  I then convert 0/1 to a/b and print.

The `z = bin(i+top)[3:]` is a bit of trickery.  The `bin` function converts a number to binary, and adds the prefix `0b`.  For numbers less than the full length, it does not pad zeros on the left, so 3 comes out `0b11` even if we want 7 digits.  So, I 0b10000000 to the number, and throw out the top three characters.  That leave a 0-padded string.

```
def solution(A,B):
    a3 = '0'*3
    b3 = '1'*3

    top = 1 << (A+B)
    for i in range(top):
        z = bin(i+top)[3:]
        if a3 in z or b3 in z:
            continue
        z = z.replace('0','a').replace('1','b')
        print( z )

solution(5,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def solve(a, b, previous):
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        return ""
    if a > b:
        if previous == "a":
            return "b" + solve(a, b - 1, "b")
        else:
            count = min(2, a)
            return "a" * count + solve(a - count, b, "a")
    else:
        if previous == "b":
            return "a" + solve(a - 1, b, "a")
        else:
            count = min(2, b)
            return "b" * count + solve(a, b - count, "b")


def solution(a, b):
    if max(a, b) > (min(a, b) + 1) * 2:
        return "Impossible"
    return solve(a, b, None)


print(solution(5, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need an answer (as opposed to all answers), you can do it iteratively in a while loop:

While there are letters to add, select 'a' and/or 'b' depending on which one has more to place and also avoid repetitions of 3.  If you end up using more that the allocated count of a given letter, this will mean that there is no solution.

```
def alternate(A,B):
    result = ""
    while A or B:
        if A<0 or B<0: return "impossible"
        useA = A >= B # use an 'a' ?
        useB = B >= A # use a 'b'  ?
        if result[-2:] == "aa": useA,useB = 0,1 # next must be 'b'
        if result[-2:] == "bb": useA,useB = 1,0 # next must be 'a'
        result += "a"*useA + "b"*useB # append letter(s)
        A,B     = A-useA, B-useB      # decrement used
    return result


print(alternate(3,5)) # bbababab
print(alternate(8,3)) # aabaabaabaa
print(alternate(3,8)) # bbabbabbabb
print(alternate(2,7)) # impossible
```